# How to document ROS2 C++ package source code?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the current best practice to document ROS2 (Bouncy, `colcon` build) C++ package source code? (According to [ros2doc templates](https://github.com/ros2/ros2doc/blob/master/templates/conf.py#L4) it seems like the `sphinx` extension `breathe` is used to post process `doxygen` generated docs.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300963/how-to-document-ros2-c++-package-source-code?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-08-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-08-21**:
That's still the plan I think. For now, I'd just use doxygen with c++ and if you want create a doxygen file in your project so it can generate documents you can do that, but what's in it may need to change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not yet any defined best practice on documenting ROS2 packages. The ROS2 style guide does [give some information](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Developer-Guide#documentation) on what should be in the documentation, but it does not prescribe a format. Use what you are familiar with, what is easy to maintain, and what produces good, readable documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-08-21**:
The main thing I am interested in is integrating nicely with the future ROS2 API build infrastructure which will generate http://docs.ros2.org/api/ (not existing yet).

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-08-21**:
If you are looking to be compatible with something that does not exist yet, then I don't think there's any answer that will help you. I suggest you use what you've already found, since they are common tools, and update when necessary.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-08-22**:
Usually some people have already something in mind which is not public yet. I just tried to get this Info already. As you said sticking to something common and migrating if necessary is a good idea.